# Quip Automation API - Not possible to Upload PDF as a blob

Tags: quip

There is a business need to attach PDF files to the thread messages.

API reference for endpoint "Add a Blob to a Thread" says 'The image or blob binary'.

But when trying to upload PDF it says

```
{
  "error": "application_error",
  "error_code": 400,
  "error_description": "Malformed image"
}
```

Will it be fixed? And when?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can only upload images via "Add a Blob to a Thread". No other type is supported. We will amend our documentation shortly.