# Upload DOCX or PDF as blob

Tags: quip

Is it possible to upload a PDF or a DOCX as a blob and attach it to a document?

I am trying to attach a blob to a document through the edit_document endpoint (the same way that a blob would get added to a document if you dragged it onto quip). I am using the python library. I am able to upload the blob with the `put_blob` call, but am unable to link to the blob from the document. I'm not quite sure what HTML is supposed to be used in the edit_document call, but I tried the `img` tag (which didn't work) and the `a` tag as well.

Looks like David said over here that it is only possible to upload images right now, has this changed recently?

[Quip Automation API - Not possible to Upload PDF as a blob](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/215242/quip-automation-api-not-possible-to-upload-pdf-as-a-blob)

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import quip

client = quip.QuipClient(access_token="...")
user = client.get_authenticated_user()

private = client.get_folder(user["private_folder_id"])
print ("There are", len(private["children"]), "items in your private folder")


threadId = None
for child in private["children"]:
  if 'thread_id' in child:
    threadId = child['thread_id']

if not threadId:
  print("no threads in folder")
  exit()

print('uploading to thread', threadId)

thefile = open('audio.mp3', 'rb')

ret = client.put_blob(threadId, thefile, name="namehere")

print(ret, ret['url'])

content = "<img src='%s' >" % ret['url']

client.edit_document(threadId, content)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload BLOB using the Quip API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/314116/how-to-upload-blob-using-the-quip-api)

Comment: Tried that unfortunately! It says to use the img tag on that Q. Seems like the img tag only works for images (and not PDFs)

Comment: The referenced question uploads audio files as blobs and references them via image tag.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. My bad. Just tried that and it didn't work unfornatuly. I tried uploading an audio file with the code sample there and it didn't work either. Just a big box shows up in quip that says "Click to add an image". Maybe I'm missing something. I'll update my questions with my code.

Comment: They are uploading to the thread (`client.put_blob(thread_id...`), you're uploading to the folder.

Comment: Fixed that bug in the code as well (introduced while simplifying the code for this Q&A). Same behavior. Thank you for the help!